# extract specific data from a csv file with specified row and column names

Tags: python, csv, data-extraction

The CSV module of python is pretty new for me and would like to get some help with a specific task.
I am looking to extract data (numeric values) from a csv-file-1 based on its row and column names. Secondly, I would like to put this data into another csv-file, in a new column, at the same line corresponding to the raw name's data from csv-file-1.

Here are examples of my two dataframes (csv format, sep = ","):
csv-file-1:

```
seq_label,id3,id4
id1,0.3,0.2
id2,0.4,0.7
```

csv-file-2:

```
seq_label,x1,...
id1,id3,...
id2,id4,...
```

For example, I would like to select values from csv-file-1, which correspond to the intersection of row names of "seq_label" and "x1" variables in csv-file-2.
Then, I would like to create a new csv-file (csv-file-3) which is the fusion of csv-file-1 and the extracted data from csv-file-1, in this way:

csv-file-3 ("x3" is the new variable or new column with extracted values):

```
seq_label,x1,...,x3
id1,id3,...,0.3
id2,id4,...,0.7
```

Could someone give me a hand on this?

Best regards

Comment: Hey! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. You should add what have you tried so far and where are you stucked at. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example with comments to explain the steps. Hope it'll help you.

```
import csv

with open("path to file", "r") as f:    # to open the file with read mode
     r = csv.reader(f)                  # create a csv reader
     content = list(r)                  # get the content of the file in a list
     column = ["x3", 0.3, 0.7, ...]     # prepare the last column
     content.append(column)             # add it to content list
     with open("path to file 2", "w") as f2 :   ## Open file 2 in order to write into it
         w = csv.writer(r, newline='')
         w.writerows(content)                   ## write the new content
```

Answer (score 0):

The csv lib will return you a list for each row.
What you want to do is

```
read the first csv
and convert it into something you can use (depends on whether you want row or column based access
do the same for csv2
for each line of csv1 search for a match in csv2
and add it to your internal data
write this data to your output file
```

You might also want to look at
https://pandas.pydata.org/
since it seems like you could save a lot of time using pandas instead of the plain csv methods.